# How to properly customize an Attribute for custom security in MVC 4?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, custom-attributes

In an intranet web application at my company, numerous operations have a granular, custom security system which is used in each action/http method in our MVC controllers.  Basically there are two enums; one is a set of actions that can be performed (this is extremely granular; practically every possible action has a corresponding value in the enum) and one is a set of our subcompanies.  For the context of this question, I will call these enums `Action` and `Company`.

Each user in our system is associated to one `Company` and zero or more `Action`s.  Inside each method in our controllers, somewhere along the way there is a check for if the current user has the right `Action` and `Company` value to be using that feature.  Every controller has a "UserHelper" injected into it which contains the `Company` and list of `Action`s the authenticated user is associated with.

Approaching it this way, there is a lot of code duplication in that every method is doing its own check on these enum values and reacting to violations when necessary.  I am hoping to reduce this all to a `System.Attribute` or `System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute` which we can put on controllers or methods to automatically handle violations in a uniform way and not have to check for it within the methods.  Something akin to:

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    [RequireActionAndCompanyAttribute(Action = Action.MyMethod, Company = Company.AbcInc)]
    MyMethod()
    {
        // do stuff, but don't bother checking for the security values
    }
}
```

As mentioned, I am assuming I can inherit from `System.Attribute` or `System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute` for this purpose.  However, I'm struggling.  I'm not sure how to adapt `AuthorizeAttribute` to use our own internal security implementation (based on `Action` and `Company`) rather than one of the ASP.NET Membership systems.  And the plain old `System.Attribute` seems so vague that I'm thinking it wasn't designed for this kind of use at all.  I'm also not sure how I'm supposed to pass anything to the methods in the attribute.  When I put the attribute on a method, I just want to specify what `Action` and `Company` are required to continue, like in the code snippet above.  But then, how do I pass the user's actual values for these into the attribute's validation method?

Comment: how are the "UserHelper" injected?

Comment: @DanielGpeReyes - As of now each controller has the UserHelper injected by parameter into its constructor and stores it in a private readonly field.

Comment: can you post your UserHelper?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a custom attribute inherited from `ActionFilterAttribute` instead of the `AuthorizeAttribute`. You can inject your `UserHelper` in this class and override the `OnActionExecuting` method and set the `Result` property of the context when your condition isn't met.

Comment: Where do I inject the UserHelper?

Comment: How do you inject it in your controller now? What kind of framework do you use? Can you resolve it from the container directly? Otherwise you can get it from the controller via the Controller property of the ActionExecutingContext

Comment: We are using the Unity dependency injection framework.  I'm not sure how to resolve something from the container.  The Controller property of the ActionExecutingContext does not have the UserHelper.

Comment: Resolving a dependency from the Unity container in MVC is quite simple: use `DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IInterfaceToResolve>();`. I think this will work for you.

Comment: For the `Controller` property to work, you need to cast it to a specific controller which wraps the UserHelper in a property. You might consider adding that property to a base controller class and inherit the specific controller from that base class. But it is much cleaner to do it with the DI method.

Comment: Well this certainly exposed my feeble understanding of dependency injection!  But yes, this worked, and now this ActionFilterAttribute is doing exactly what I need.  One question, is there any reason I should be called base.OnActionExecuting within my OnActionExecuting method?

Comment: No, see the source of the base class, the method is empty: https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/release/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Core/Filters/ActionFilterAttribute.cs